Text Alignment in R Magick package
I am trying to align text to its placement coordinate centrally using the magick package in R and image_annotate...
So in this example
#Load Graphic
pb<-image_read("https://art.pixilart.com/8c9cffeb529b204.png")
#Place text at central coordinate
image_draw(pb) %>% 
  image_annotate("Centre",location=geometry_point(610.5,610.5), color = "red", size = 50)

the top right of the word "Centre" is(roughly) aligned with the provided coordinate.
Is it possible to set a command (equivalent to hjust, vjust etc) that would align the text centrally....
it seems that although ImageMagick might have some of this functionality, it doesn't look like all the commands and parameters have ported over to the R package (though I may be missing something)

Does this work?
library(magick)

#Load Graphic
pb<-image_read("https://art.pixilart.com/8c9cffeb529b204.png")
#Place text at central coordinate
image_draw(pb) |>  
  image_annotate("Centre",
                 color = "red", 
                 size = 50,
                 gravity = "center")



I almost specified that I didn't want to use gravity as that changes the whole coordinate system - I would like to keep the coordinate system based on an origin in one of the left hand corners (ideally it would have been the bottom left but am dealing  with in in the top right).
Is there any other way?  (I note that ImageMagick might have  had a text_align - it seems to have been quite a hot topic c2007-2012!)?

I didn't want to be too specific as I didn't want to rule out anything - it could be that an answer might have been "Use gravity, but you can also keep a corner based coordinate system by doing....."
after reflecting on this for a night, I am going to have a try at using gravity, it could be that automatically converting the coordinates from a corner origin to centre origin system might solve the issue - so your time wasn't wasted! Thanks.
I still can't believe that they don't separate out the two "features" of te gravity command though!

Fair dos; thanks for that! The thing is that gravity seems to be what sets the coordinate reference point so can use both. When I was thinking about it the issue with using a pure coordinate system to "centre" the text is that you would need to know the length of the bounding box associated with the text. This "measure" of text length is available  in grid graphics but I am not familiar enough with either grid or magick to know if the two can be linked.
